# Is there an easy way to do wrap this in sublime text?

Tags: sublimetext3

```
names = [Joey
Aurelio
Evan
Donny
Foster
Dwayne
Grady
Quinton
Darin
Mickey
Hank
Kim
Peter
Jeremy
Jess
Jimmie]
```

I want the names to appear as:

```
names = ['Joey', 'Aurelio','Evan', 'Donny',.....,'Jimmie']
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Manually select all the names inside the brackets.
2. Select **`Selection → Split into Lines`**, which makes each name its own selection.
3. Press the single quote <kbd>'</kbd> key, which places a quote `'` before each selection.
4. Press the right arrow <kbd>→</kbd> key, which creates multiple cursors, one at the end of each word.
5. Press the single quote <kbd>'</kbd> then the comma <kbd>,</kbd> key, which adds the closing single quote and a comma `,` after each name. If you wish, you can then press <kbd>Space</kbd> followed by the forward delete <kbd>Delete</kbd> key to erase the newlines and put all the names on the same line.
6. Manually navigate to the end of the list, remove the last comma, and re-add the closing bracket `]`.